# C# processing XML

Tags: c#

I have the following XML file which I am trying to parse using XmlDocument in C#. I am just a starter and searched around the internet for a solution. Partly it's working now, but I can figure out the last details.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(FileIn);
            XmlNodeList Mydocs = doc.SelectNodes("/Array-Doc/Doc");
```

I am able to loop over the doc array but not able to loop through the XLSX and XLSX_CLUSTER arrays to take out the filename and the row info. Any suggestions how to solve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Array-Doc>
    <Doc>
        <XLSX>
        <Create>1</Create>
        <FileName>d:\tmp\filename1</FileName>
        <Array-Rows>
            <Rows>
            <Row>test1;test2</Row>
            <ColorFill>0</ColorFill>
            <Bold>1</Bold>
            </Rows>
            <Rows>
            <Row>test3;test4</Row>
            <ColorFill>1</ColorFill>
            <Bold>0</Bold>
            </Rows>
        </Array-Rows>
        </XLSX>
    <IndexForMerge>0</IndexForMerge>
    <ExcelFileNeeded>1</ExcelFileNeeded>
        <XLSX_CLUSTER>
        <Create>1</Create>
        <FileName>d:\tmp\filename1</FileName>
        <Array-Rows>
            <Rows>
            <Row>test5;test6</Row>
            <ColorFill>0</ColorFill>
            <Bold>1</Bold>
            </Rows>
            <Rows>
            <Row>test7;test8</Row>
            <ColorFill>0</ColorFill>
            <Bold>0</Bold>
            </Rows>
        </Array-Rows>
        </XLSX_CLUSTER>
    <ExcelFileNeededCluster>1</ExcelFileNeededCluster>
    </Doc>
    <Doc>
        <XLSX>
        <Create>1</Create>
        <FileName>d:\tmp\filename2</FileName>
        <Array-Rows>
            <Rows>
            <Row>test9;test10</Row>
            <ColorFill>0</ColorFill>
            <Bold>1</Bold>
            </Rows>
            <Rows>
            <Row>test11;test12</Row>
            <ColorFill>1</ColorFill>
            <Bold>0</Bold>
            </Rows>
        </Array-Rows>
        </XLSX>
    <IndexForMerge>0</IndexForMerge>
    <ExcelFileNeeded>1</ExcelFileNeeded>
        <XLSX_CLUSTER>
        <Create>1</Create>
       <FileName>d:\tmp\filename2</FileName>
       <Array-Rows>
            <Rows>
            <Row>test13;test14</Row>
            <ColorFill>0</ColorFill>
            <Bold>1</Bold>
            </Rows>
            <Rows>
            <Row>test15;test16</Row>
            <ColorFill>0</ColorFill>
            <Bold>0</Bold>
            </Rows>
        </Array-Rows>
        </XLSX_CLUSTER>
    <ExcelFileNeededCluster>1</ExcelFileNeededCluster>
    </Doc>
</Array-Doc>
```

Here the code I developed till now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using FlexCel.Core;
using FlexCel.XlsAdapter;
using System.Xml;

namespace CreateExcel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime Start = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Start = " + Start);
            String RowText = "";
            int RowCounter = 0;
            int ColumnCounter = 0;
            String FileIn = args[0];
            String FileOut = args[1];
            //
            // Read XML
            //
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(FileIn);
            XmlNodeList Mydocs = doc.SelectNodes("/Array-Doc/Doc");
            //
            // Create and Excel per doc 
            //
            for (int i = 0; i < Mydocs.Count; i++)
            //foreach (XmlNode MyDoc in Mydocs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Count I = " + i);
                XmlNodeList XLSX = doc.SelectNodes("/Mydocs[i]/XLSX");
                for (int j = 0; j < XLSX.Count; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Count J = " + j);
                    **String test = XLSX[j].SelectSingleNode["FileName"];**
                }
            }
            DateTime Stop = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Stop = " + Stop);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What  have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: I added above the code I created till now. But no idea how to extract the filename.

It's around the line: XmlNodeList XLSX = doc.SelectNodes("/Mydocs[i]/XLSX"); no idea how to come to the correct statement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument` instead of `System.Xml.XmlDocument`? It's a bit easier to use - you don't need to use XPath etc.

For example:

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
foreach(var doc in xmlDoc.Descendants("Doc")) {
    foreach(var xlsx in doc.Descendants("XLSX")) {
        var fileName = xlsx.Element("FileName");
    }
}
```